# adding errorprone to gradle build file

Tags: gradle, errorprone

I am trying to add errorprone to my gradle build file as follows:

**relevant parts of build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.0.9"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'idea'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.4'
    id "net.ltgt.errorprone" version "0.0.9"
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.0.9'
}

configurations.errorprone {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.0.19'
}
```

**error from classpath line when I run gradle clean**

```
 Could not find method classpath() for arguments [net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.0.9] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Any thoughts on what is causing this issue and what might help resolve this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got errorprone to work with gradle by making the following changes:

1. **replaced this from dependencies**:

   classpath net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.0.9'

with

```
 errorprone "com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:latest.release"
```

2. and **removed the configurations line**:

   configurations.errorprone {
       resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.0.19'
   }

This worked.